# Start activity on kitkat devices

Tags: android

This is thrown when trying to open activity using `context.startActivity(intent)`

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback23Impl not present
```

All activities extends `AppCompatActivity` and I am calling `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)` inside a static block of my application.

On newer android versions everyting is ok.

Does anybody met this issue and can share info how to solve it?

Here my gradle configuration

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    lintOptions {
        disable 'RestrictedApi'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias '****'
            keyPassword '*************'
            storeFile file('../release.jks')
            storePassword '*************'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***.****"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.0.3"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 26
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }

         debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
 }

 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
 }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
     }
 }

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':googleemoji')
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.22.0') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev44-1.22.0') {
         exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.4.0'
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: do you have a full stacktrace for the exception?